# Why does executereader behave like this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I can not find the correct sollution to this strange behavior.
In another project, this works like a charm.
Its when i resolve sqlconnection and using using System.Data.SqlClient it makes this red underline under executereader.... Why does it behave like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //*********************************
        //Definerer connection stringen   *
        //*********************************
        SqlConnection BilleddataBasen = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Boligforeningen_AB8"].ConnectionString);

        //**************************************
        //Definerer de forskellige variabler   *
        //**************************************
        string ImageFilePath = "";
        string ImageName = "";
        string OverfoereDataTilImageControlPaaAspxSiden = "";

        //**************************************************
        //Definerer hvordan der skal læses fra databasen   *
        //**************************************************
        SqlCommand SelectBlogIndlæg = new SqlCommand("SELECT FileName, FilePath, OprettelsesDato, Tittel, BilledetsIndhold FROM BillederTilGalleri", BilleddataBasen);

        BilleddataBasen.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = BilleddataBasen.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ImageName += reader["FileName"];
            ImageFilePath += reader["FilePath"];
            lbl_OprettelsesDato.Text += reader["OprettelsesDato"];
            lbl_BilledNavnet.Text += reader["Tittel"];
            lbl_BeskrivelseAfBilledet.Text += reader["BilledetsIndhold"];
        }

        OverfoereDataTilImageControlPaaAspxSiden = ImageFilePath + ImageName;
        lbl_BilledFraDataBasen.ImageUrl = OverfoereDataTilImageControlPaaAspxSiden;

        //************************************************
        //Følgende to linier bestemmer pixel størrelse   *
        //************************************************

        lbl_BilledFraDataBasen.Width = 300;
        lbl_BilledFraDataBasen.Height = 250;

        //*************************************
        //Lukker ned for database tilgangen   *
        //*************************************
        reader.Close();
        BilleddataBasen.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. As it stands I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Well where the red 'underline' bit is, does it show an error? Does it give an error when you compile?

Comment: Well... It tells me that i am missing an assambly reference. Yet, rightclicking on it, does not give me an "resolve" option.

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.Data?

Comment: Still the same. Sorry...

Answer (score 3):

[`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) doesn't have an `ExecuteReader` method. [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) does. You should be calling:

```
SqlDataReader reader = SelectBlogIndlæg.ExecuteReader();
```

Note that when you built, the compiler error message should have provided you with all the information you need to diagnose this yourself - at least the first part. It's worth taking a step back to work out how you could have fixed this for yourself (and therefore how you can fix the next problem).

As asides:

- You should be using `using` statements for all your resources (connection, command, reader)List item
- Concatenating strings in a loop is generally a bad idea (and in this case it doesn't look like you've got a separator, so your values will all be smeared together)
- Conventionally variables are use camelCase rather than PascalCase

Also, you stated:

> In another project, this works like a charm.

That's simply not true. The code you've given would *not* work in any project.

Comment: I didn't notice that! Nice pick up! Perhaps it was the non-English naming convention..

Comment: Nope... Sorry. When setting the variable. And changing selectblogindlæg tobilleddatabasen, it still gives me an error.

Comment: That's not *nearly* enough information. "An error" could be anything. Additionally, you should *try* to fix this for yourself - we're not going to spoon-feed you a fix to every single error.

Comment: Sorry... I am new to this stuff... Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: And yes... The code DOES work in another project... I have written it. And as why it does not work now, i do not know. Thats why a noob like me is asking people who knows more than me.'

Comment: @Anders: I simply don't believe you. You're trying to call `ExecuteReader` on `SqlConnection`. That method doesn't exist. I suggest you look at the code in the project which works, and you'll find it's different. Note that however new you are to C#, that doesn't mean you can't provide relevant information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13450020/BlogTraade.aspx.cs

Comment: That's the code wich DOES work. Sorry... I am just missing out on something. And what it is. I don't know

Comment: @Anders, this needs changing, on Default3.aspx.cs:         `SqlDataReader reader = BilleddataBasen.ExecuteReader();`...it works for the other page because it's correct code. On `Default2`, you are calling it on the `SqlCommand` itself, whereas on `Default3`, you are calling it on the `SqlConnection`.

Comment: @Arran... I have to read that a couple of times. I have under one year of practice on this.

Comment: @Anders: Right, so the working code has exactly the change I suggested: calling `SelectBlogIndlæg.ExecuteReader()` instead of `BilleddataBasen.ExecuteReader()`. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: Well... Not shure why I could not see it now... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are calling ExecuteReader on your SqlConnection object, You should call it on your Command object instead.

```
SqlDataReader reader = SelectBlogIndlæg.ExecuteReader();
```